# Is there a way to see the workspace of a given changeset?

Tags: tfs, workspace, changeset, checkin

Is there a way, by any means, to get the workspace from where a specific check-in was made?

Using Team Foundation Sidekicks I can see the workspace, computer and local path of current checked-out items, but not of changesets. Does TFS keep track of this?

**Update**

It might help to explain what I really want. Someone performed a check-in using another team member's account (or at least that is what he alleges haha), and I was trying to get to the bottom of this mess by finding the workspace of the changeset because it contains enough information to make a call. Right now the only information I have besides the comment is the date and time, but perhaps there is something else I could use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. I've spent some time looking at our TFS Collection Database, and I cannot find anything that links a changeset to a workspace.

The tables that I've been using have been:

- ADObjects
- tbl_Workspace
- tbl_WorkspaceMapping
- tbl_Changeset
- tbl_LocalVersion
- tbl_PendingChange

Because a workspace only deals with items that are stored on the local machine, I don't believe that information is sent up to the TFS server when a changeset is committed.

Comment: Thank you for taking some time to look into this, I appreciate it! What you say makes total sense, I was thinking the same, just wanted to see if anyone knew better. I will wait a bit for any new information on the subject and accept your answer otherwise.