# How to get the workspace ID from a changeset in TFS?

Tags: tfs, version-control, changeset

I have many workspaces that I manage locally while working with our source control system - sometimes though, I will go over 6 months without working on a particular codebase, and *just in case* I'd like to check which workspace the last changeset came from.

This way I could ensure that no "rogue" files have been worked on locally without being checked in - I know it "shouldn't" happen if I'm checking in on every change, this is just a safety mechanism.

I know I can get the changeset ID from TFS 2017 by looking at the repository in the "Code" section - is there any way to tell which local workspace that changeset came from?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using branches instead of separate workspaces.

Comment: @DanielMann - I don't think it's a branching issue, this is just "checking" to see if the last physical location has unchecked-in changes. I don't see how branching would resolve that concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's not able to achieve this.  Changesets contain the history of each item in version control. You can view a changeset to get information about:

- which files were changed
- what the exact changes were
- who changed the files
- what the check-in comment contains
- which work items are associated with the changeset
- which policy warnings appeared

It's not able to view the workspace info from changeset directly, even through database. A local workspace only deals with items that are stored on the local machine,  such information would not be sent up to the TFS server when a changeset is committed. Take a look at this similar question: [Is there a way to see the workspace of a given changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764473/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-workspace-of-a-given-changeset)

You have to manually compare each workspace  with server version or do the opposite-- [How do I check which changeset my workspace is in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461654/how-do-i-check-which-changeset-my-workspace-is-in)